# metodo del. no funciona de la forma que yo pense

Tags: python, python-2.7

*Quiero crear un mazo de cartas que saca la primera carta despues que lo barajea*

```
from random import shuffle

def doing_deck():
    value = ['a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k']
    suits = ['H','D','S','C',]
    cards = []

    for i in range(len(value)):
        for x in range(4):
            carlos =  [value[i] , suits[x]]
            carlos = "".join(carlos)
            cards.append(carlos)
    return cards

cards1 = doing_deck() #cards1 agarra cards sin combinar

def get_shuffled_deck():
    shuffle(cards1)
    return cards1

list1 = get_shuffled_deck()     
print list1

def deal_card(list1):
    print list1[0]
    del list1[0]

deal_card(list1)
print list1

get_shuffled_deck()
```

`Deal_card()` toma un argumento (una lista) y debería hacer dos cosas: remover el primer elemento y retornarlo. El problema es que simplemente lo elimina. ¿Cómo podría hacer lo que deseo?

Comment: **[Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour)**. lee 
**[cómo crear una buena pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)**. **Debes [edit] tu pregunta** agregando la explicación de este código, cuáles son los problemas que tienes con este código y la descripción de los errores. que puedas tener

Comment: Como comenta Mauricio deberias explicar que se supone que deberia hacer `del` y que no está haciendo. El caso es que `del list1[0]`  hace lo que se espera, elimina el primer item de `list1`, ni más ni menos. ¿Que se supone que quieres que haga?

Comment: .
Deal_card() esta funcion toma un argumento , una lista , y tiene que hacer dos cosas , remorver lo del index 0 y retornar lo que quito

Comment: La información que sea relevante para tu pregunta debes añadirla a la propia pregunta, no en comentarios. Para ello basta con editarla. Intenta redactar siempre la pregunta correctamente, con el código correctamente formateado e identado (sobretodo en Python) y explicando detenidamente que hace el código, que debería  hacer, que errores tienes, etc.  Por ser nuevo por estos lares te la he editado por esta vez :), pero recuerdalo para otras ocasiones , de lo contrario o terminará cerrada o será difícil obtener buenas respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Si , es la primera vez que pregunto y utilizo stackoverflow, gracias por responder la duda.
Mas bien , tengo una pregunta . Estoy usando una pagina para aprender codigo online y cuando subo mi codigo (El de las cartas) La pagina corre unos test y sale que fallan no se que hacer, te dejo un ejemplo :
deal_card_5
It looks like the card that was dealt was not removed from the deck.
More info
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python", line 53, in test_deal_card_5
AssertionError: 45 != 51

Comment: ¿De que página y que ejercicio se trata?

Comment: Tengo que traspasar lo mismo pero usando clases : In this project, you will build on your code from the last project. By the end of this project, you will have a class that represents a deck of cards and another class that represents a single card.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para que elimine y retorne el elemento debes usar el método `pop(index)`, `del` solo lo elimina pero no retorna nada.

```
def deal_card(list1):
    return list1.pop(0)

carta = deal_card(list1)
print(carta)
print(list1)
```

Otra recomendación es que para combinar las cartas no uses indices, itera directamente sobre los elemntos. Es más 'pythónico' y más eficiente:

```
def doing_deck():
    value = ['a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k']
    suits = ['H','D','S','C',]
    cards = []

    for v in value:
        for x in suits:
            carlos = "".join((v,x))
            cards.append(carlos)
    return cards
```

O usa directamente compresión de listas:

```
def doing_deck():
    value = ['a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k']
    suits = ['H','D','S','C',]
    return ["".join((v,x)) for x in suits for v in values]
```

Otra opción eficiente es usar `itertools.product()`.

El código podría quedar así:

```
from random import shuffle
from itertools import product

def doing_deck():
    value = ['a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k']
    suits = ['H','D','S','C',]
    return ["".join((v,x)) for v, x in product(value, suits)]

def get_shuffled_deck(cards):
    shuffle(cards)

def deal_card(cards):
    return cards.pop(0)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print 'Obteniendo mazo de cartas'
    cards = doing_deck()
    print 'Barajando...'
    get_shuffled_deck(cards)
    carta1 = deal_card(cards)
    print 'Primera carta obtenida: {}.'.format(carta1)
    get_shuffled_deck(cards)
    print('Barajando...')
    carta2 = deal_card(cards)
    print 'Segunda carta obtenida: {}.'.format(carta2)
```